Using APS to convert files
Revit native FBX exporter does not seem to have the ability to export textures and materials with the FBX file, but this is something I would like to do as part of an automated pipeline.
I have noticed however that 3ds Max can import RVT files and can export as FBX with embedded textures.
Is it possible via any of the APS (Forge) SDKs/APIs to enable this process?

I haven't tried yet, but it should be possible to use Design Automation API to load a Revit file in 3ds Max instance and export FBX out of it.
I experimented a long ago with some Design Automation for 3ds Max workflows, that can be found here.
Note that these Postman workflows rely on Auth 1.0 which is now depriacated in favour of Auth 2.0, so you have to adjust the acquiring of 2L token (I will try to update it this week).
If you are new to Design Automation, apart from official tutorial have also look at this tutorial.
